# Netty dependency issue with ElasticSearch 6.3.2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm using spring boot and trying to connect with Elasticsearch recent version 6.3.2 but couldn't Do we need to specify any appropriate jar version

Error:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/internal/logging/InternalLoggerFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Utils.<clinit>(Netty4Utils.java:49) ~[transport-netty4-client-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin.<clinit>(Netty4Plugin.java:48) ~[transport-netty4-client-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:696) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:114) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.newPluginService(TransportClient.java:107) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:132) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:280) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:128) ~[transport-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:114) ~[transport-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:104) ~[transport-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
    at com.techprimers.elastic.standaloneelasticexample.resource.UsersResource.<init>(UsersResource.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

---

The Java Code:

```
TransportClient client;

        public UsersResource() throws UnknownHostException {
            client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                    .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
            //client.close();

        }
```

Below I have given configuration of POM

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.elastic</groupId>
<artifactId>standalone-elastic-example</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>standalone-elastic-example</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <elasticsearch.version>6.3.2</elasticsearch.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Did I miss any dependency ?

What causing this issue not able to connect. Kindly let me know in case of any further information.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not solve your NoClassDefFoundError but you should probably start using  "Java High Level REST Client" since elasticsearch is planning to deprecate the TransportClient in Elasticsearch 7.0 and removing it completely in 8.0.So, it's better to use Java High Level REST Client instead of transport client.

More details are available [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html).

Comment: Thanks for this good info, but currently I'm using version 6 right then this issue should not come right

Comment: Ideally It should work,could you try using webmvc(with tomcat or jetty) instead of netty and if it works you know issue is related to netty,